# Auto create Class Properties based on SQL Table Columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell

My main language is powershell, i know how to do what i want using powershell, but i don't know how to do it with c#,

well, i have some sql tables with different column names, i want to create a list/array with all the results, i know that i need to create a class for each table, each with different properties based on the column names, then fill each property with the corresponding column value,

the problem is that i don't want to create a different class with different props for each table, i want to create list with all the column names for each table then create the class properties automatically based on the column names. to explain what i mean, using powershell:

let's take this table:

```
id  ReportDate  Volume  Capacity    FreeSpace   PercentFree
1   23/03/2017 12:59    C   279 28.7    10.3
2   23/03/2017 12:59    E   1117    756.3   67.7
3   23/03/2017 12:59    G   62464   38445.6 61.5
4   23/03/2017 12:59    H   466 414.2   88.9
```

in powershell i can create a simple array with the column names:

```
$Columns = @('id','ReportDate','Volume','Capacity','FreeSpace','PercentFree')
```

Then i create an object:

```
$Row = "" | Select ($Columns | % {$_})
```

`$Row` will look like this:

```
id          : 
ReportDate  : 
Volume      : 
Capacity    : 
FreeSpace   : 
PercentFree :
```

Then i can fill it with the table values:

in c# i must declare the properties for the class when i create it (as much as i know) for example:

```
public class SqlTable
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string ReportDate { get; set; }
        public string Volume { get; set; }
        [...] etc...
    }
```

So, how can i create a dynamic class property names based on the table columns in c# like the powershell example without creating a different class with different props for each table..? is it possible? if not, what are the available options?

sorry for the long question, i hope i explaind it right...
Thanks.

Comment: Hard to know for sure, but it sounds like you want a `DataTable` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8

Comment: how this can help? can you show some explanation please...

Comment: If that doesn't help then I don't understand your question. I gave you a link with example of what I'm guessing you want to so.